# How to get name current bramch name in a git repository using python

Tags: python, git, pygit2

This is the script to get the current branch name in git using ssh key

```
URL = raw_input('Enter the ssh git URL: ')
print URL
from pygit2 import Repository
repo = Repository(URL)

# option 1
head = repo.head
print("Head is " + head.name)

# option 2
head = repo.lookup_reference('HEAD').resolve()
print("Head is " + head.name)
```

Error:It is showing repository not found.Please help to get the current branch name in git repository

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Clone.py", line 28, in <module>
    Repository(URL).head.shorthand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygit2/repository.py", line 1184, in __init__
    path_backend = init_file_backend(path)
_pygit2.GitError: Repository not found at git@gitlab.com:Manoj.ck/sampleproject.git
```

Comment: Could you provide the URL that you're trying?

Comment: @Anwarvic url:git@gitlab.com:Manoj.ck/sampleproject.git

Comment: Why can't I find this URL? I even can't clone it... maybe that's the problem, The URL. Could you double-check the URL?

Comment: @Anwarvic this is ssh url for git repository so this might not work in browser

Comment: I tried to clone it, but I couldn't

Comment: @Anwarvic try with this http url: " https://gitlab.com/Manoj.ck/sampleproject.git" i am getting same error for this url also

Comment: @Anwarvic when i click the above link pasted it is working fine for me

Comment: Great!! the problem was within the provided URL

Comment: @Anwarvic what is the problem and how can i fix it

Comment: @kishore I think you need to first [clone](http://pygit2.org/repository.html?highlight=repository#pygit2.clone_repository) the repository and then use Repository's [constructor](https://www.pygit2.org/repository.html?highlight=repository#pygit2.Repository) to open the repository

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [the GitPython tutorial](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html), a clone would be:

```
from git import Repo

cloned_repo = repo.clone("<url>")
```